# Calculating the average of several function invocations using closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I am doing a coding challenge that reads like this:

Create a function runningAverage() that returns a callable function object. Update the series with each given value and calculate the current average.

```
rAvg = runningAverage();
rAvg(10) = 10.0;
rAvg(11) = 10.5;
rAvg(12) = 11;
```

I got a working solution, yet they also want the results to be rounded like this:

```
rAvg(13) = 13.50678; => 13.50
rAvg(13) = 13.50; => 13.50
rAvg(13) = 13.5; => 13.5
rAvg(13) = 13; => 13
```

Here is my code:

```
function runningAverage() {

  let number = 0;
  let numbOfFunctionCalls = 0;
  
  return function (y) {

    number += y;
    numbOfFunctionCalls ++;
    let average = (number/numbOfFunctionCalls);
    let averageArray = average.toString().split('.');

    //to get the number of decimal places
    //e.g 11.543 ==> ['11', '543']
    if ((Array.from(averageArray[1]).length) >= 2) {
      return average.toPrecision(2);
    }

    else if ((Array.from(averageArray[1]).length) = 1) {
      return average.toPrecision(1);
    }

    else {
      return average;
    }
  
  }
}
```

I tested parts of the function separately and it seems to work, yet when I invoke it I get the message 'cannot convert undefined or null to object'.

Comment: design pattern looks bad

Comment: I don't get the rounding scheme that is expected. Can you elaborate?

Comment: These `Array.from` calls don't make much sense. Also try to avoid treating numbers as strings if you can. Specifically, notice that `.toString().split('.')` will return a single-element array for integers (that have no decimal point), and `averageArray[1]` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Also, notice the typo `= 1` vs `== 1`.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for your suggestions! I used the Array.from method to get the length of the ---average[1]-- element. I do understand that the function won't work for integers as it is right now, but don't get why it does not work for decimal numbers. The rounding scheme is, that the number gets rounded to two decimal places if there are two or more decimal places, to 1 decimal place if there is only one etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a fun coding challenge!

1. In this case, you want `toFixed()`, not `toPrecision()`. `toPrecision()` essentially allows you determine how many digits TOTAL (including those on the left of the decimal point) should appear, whereas `toFixed()` focuses on the number of digits to the ***right*** of the decimal point. Feel free to look these two methods up on MDN. When you read that `toPrecision()` may return exponential notation, this should make you pause and think, "That's weird. Why does this happen? When does this happen?", rather than "this detail is unimportant."
2. Your `.length = 1` comparison needs to be modified to a `===`.
3. Your code currently fails if an integer is the first number provided to `rAvg()`. In your first conditional, `Array.from(undefined)` may run, which is not permissible in JavaScript. You should consider ways to only work with "the digits to the right of the decimal" only if "there are digits to the right of the decimal."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution including all the suggestions, in case someone is interested:

```
function runningAverage() {

  let number = 0;
  let numbOfFunctionCalls = 0;
  
  return function (y) {

    number += y;
    numbOfFunctionCalls ++;
    let average = (number/numbOfFunctionCalls);
    let numIsDecimal = average.toString().includes('.');


    if (numIsDecimal) {
      
    let averageArray = average.toString().split('.');

    //to get the number of decimal places
    //e.g 11.543 ==> ['11', '543']
    if ((Array.from(averageArray[1]).length) >= 2) {
      return Number(average.toFixed(2));
    }
  
    if ((Array.from(averageArray[1]).length) === 1) {
      return Number(average.toFixed(1));
    }

    }

    else {
      return Number(average);
    }
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this works but try it

```js
function runningAverage() {
    let number = 0;
    let numbOfFunctionCalls = 0;
    
    return function (y) {
        number += y;
        numbOfFunctionCalls ++;

        let average = (number/numbOfFunctionCalls);
        let averageArray = average.toString().split('.');
    
        if ((Array.from(averageArray[1]).length) >= 2) {
            return Math.round(average.toPrecision(2) * 2) / 2;
        } else if ((Array.from(averageArray[1]).length) == 1) {
            return Math.round(average.toPrecision(1) * 2) / 2;
        } else {
            return Math.round(average * 2) / 2;
        };
    };
};
```